# Failed to load toolbox item in VIsual Studio in WinForms C++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a windows form application in managed C++. To add a custom user control either one can create a new project or add CLR User control to same project. When I add a user control to same project it builds and shows control in toolbar. When I drag and drop it onto my main UI it throws up error.
**"Failed to load toolbox item, It will be removed from Toolbox".**

There is no error if I create a separate project under same solution and compile control as a DLL. Is there a way I can add a custom user control to same project and use it.

Also I looked up similar question on the topc but none of them has helped me. I have checked the files and I am building the project as Win32 and there is no way control being separately built as x64.

Comment: After much research and web crawling , I think it is impossible to do it without creating a DLL via a separate project under same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem after one or both of renaming project or/and changing platform, most posted "solutions" provided to other people asking the same question didn't seem to work.

What did work for me was to go into the project folder and delete the obj folder, and just to be safe the bin folder too, then build again.  (Seems the so called Build->Clean menu item only does half of the required work.)